# Can subject and verb come after the rest of the sentence?

Tags: verbs, subjects

At times, during commentary, commentators speak sentences like "Playing well, Victor is", "A great player, Steven was".

Comment: 'A great player, Steven was.' is in the CompSV form, with an added comma to show where one would pause in speaking. 'Playing well, Victor is.' splits and re-orders the verb phrase. It is more informal, and better avoided in formal writing.

Comment: OK, thanks! Any suggestion on punctuation I used there?

Comment: The jurisdictional question is Which part has been moved? Has the `subj + aux` been moved to the end, or has the predicate phrase been moved to the front? Also, since this is **spoken** English, there are no punctuation standards; do what you think best.

Comment: This is spoken _British_ English.

Comment: This is Yoda Speak. There are online generators that will convert any regular sentence for you. ("Yoda speak, this is. Convert any regular sentence for you, there are online generators that will.  Hmmmmmm.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's grammatical but it's "marked", meaning that this word order isn't the normal declarative order but is chosen intentionally to create emphasis. Even then, it isn't usual, and I'm surprised by your implication that commentators are using it frequently. However, sometimes this order is used for humorous effect, as it reflects the sentence construction of the character Yoda in the *Star Wars* movies.

Your punctuation is correct.

Comment: Difficult to consider without Yoda, this is.